# React-Native Source-Maps for files not imported in dev

Tags: react-native, source-maps

I'm building a React-Native application using a language that has a similar compiler chain to Typescript. The language is transpiled to javascript and React-Native seems to be ignoring the source map files sitting next to the `.js` files. The primary difference with what I'm using from typescript is that it compiles everything to a single .js file (with a matching source map). This makes exceptions particularly annoying to debug.

**How do you get react-native to stop ignoring the source-map files sitting next to the `.js` files for dev builds?**

[image: Exception]

Comment: I created a bug in the expo github as well. It has a reproducting project as well - https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2061

Comment: This sometimes also occurs with typescript which is compiled to javascript. I just kind of accepted it and started to lock at the generated file. Most of the time I could recognize where in my code I was. Not a solution but... yeah meh.